# How to return boolean (primitive) in java?

Tags: java

I'm new to java and as such, I'm not entirely sure if I did this right. What I'm trying to do is find out if the number of items in a list of Strings is even and a primitive.

```
public class LearnAboutInputs { 
    public boolean isEven(String[] value) {
        if (value.size() % 2 == 0 && boolean == true) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by  "the number of items in a list of Strings is ... a primitive"?

Comment: `boolean` is a reserved word for the boolean type.  You can't treat it like a variable.  What do you think `boolean == true` is supposed to do?

Comment: Remove "&& boolean == true",add null check for parameterand method will work as expected. But did not understand the question behind

Comment: Don't feel bad if you don't understand all of the answers provided! That is something that comes with time but is also why coding is such a beautiful, yet confusing thing! As you can see, there are numerous ways to accomplish the same task!

Answer (score 5):

What you put there is not valid.  A minimal edit to make it valid would be:

```
public class LearnAboutInputs { 
    public boolean isEven(String[] value) {
        if(value.length % 2 == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
```

This assumes you intended to look at the length of the array, as opposed to looking at the size() of a string or strings within.

However, the if check is in itself boolean, so you could more succinctly write:

```
public class LearnAboutInputs { 
    public boolean isEven(String[] value) {
        return value.length % 2 == 0;
    }
```

SeeDart and PoisonedYouth bring up a good point about null checking, so adding that to the succinct example results in:

```
public class LearnAboutInputs { 
    public boolean isEven(String[] value) {
        return value != null && value.length % 2 == 0;
    }
```

If the value is null, the statement short-circuits to false, so the second half won't be evaluated, making this valid.

If you want to return an object of class [`Boolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) rather than a [primitive](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Primitive_Types) `boolean`, change the return type from lowercase ‘boolean’ to the initial-cap ‘Boolean’ word. The handy [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) features will do the legwork for you.

```
public class LearnAboutInputs { 
    public Boolean isEven(String[] value) {  // Return object rather than primitive.
        return value != null && value.length % 2 == 0;  // Autoboxing transforms the generated `boolean` primitive value into a `Boolean` object.
    }
```

Comment: Missing null check

Comment: @poisonedYouth thought of that as I pushed the button.  Thanks, though!

Comment: I'm wondering though, there is a difference between Boolean and boolean right? One's an object and the other's a primitive. So, how does Java know that I want my return to a primitive vs an object?

Comment: Java (and a computer in general) never knows what you want, it only knows what you tell it.  In this case, you have told it that the method is returning a primitive boolean type in your method signature, and Java did exactly that!  With that said, should you actually want the Boolean object, I believe all you need to do is make the method a Boolean type, and [the handy autoboxing features](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) will do the legwork for you.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is almost correct. There were a few syntax errors I fixed but I'm not sure what you were trying to do with `boolean == true`. It's also good practice to make sure your input is valid!

```
public class LearnAboutInputs { 
    public boolean isEven(String[] value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (value.length % 2 == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why you don't write `return value != null && value.length % 2 == 0;`? the code would be much shorter and easier to read

Comment: What happens if `value` is `null`? Second, I was basing my response off of the level of the question. While your answer is more readable to most, it might be easier for someone to understand the more verbose code I posted.

Comment: when `value==null` -> `false` is returned

Comment: I was addressing your post pre-edit, where you didn't have the null check.

Answer (score 0):

There are various things here. Lets rewrite:

```
public class LearnAboutInputs { 
  public boolean hasEvenLength(String[] value) {
    if (value != null && value.length % 2 == 0) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Reasonable changes here:

- changing the method name to say what the method is doing!
- avoiding the else-block; simply not required here - and not having the else block makes it even more clear how the possible control flows look like